# Unable to create class Component for material ui ColorlibStepIcon in typescript format

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My objective is to create Stepper as class component, but i could not able to do the ColorlibStepIcon functional component into class component.

I've tried but it is showing couple of errors.

[Here is the working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pejcm)

In this way i've tried (i've commented the code in the above link):

```
class ColorlibStepIcon extends React.Component(StepIconProps, PState) {
  constructor(props: StepIconProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      icons: { 1: <SettingsIcon />, 2: <GroupAddIcon />, 3: <VideoLabelIcon /> }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { active, completed } = this.props;
    const classes = this.useColorlibStepIconStyles();

    return (
      <div
        className={clsx(classes.root, {
          [classes.active]: active,
          [classes.completed]: completed
        })}
      >
        {icons[String(props.icon)]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

One more query, can anyone help in **handleNext method** also?

```
 handleNext = () => {
     setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };
```

Can anyone please help me in making class component. I was stuck from days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should't use JSX inside of state's prop. It's not a react way and to my mind not too good approach.
It's better to make it much easier.
For instance I am using functional components and hooks but you can take an idea at least.

just have a look.

components inside of render right away  ( I prefer this)

```
interface State {
    currentStep: number;
}

export class StepsSimpleClassComponent extends React.Component<StepIconProps, State> {
    private stepsCount = 1 // from zero;

    public state: State = {
        currentStep: 0
    }

    private handlePrev = () => {
        const result = this.state.currentStep - 1;

        this.setState({
            currentStep: result < 0 ? 0 : result
        })
    }

    private handleNext = () => {
        const result = this.state.currentStep + 1;

        this.setState({
            currentStep: result > this.stepsCount ? 1 : result
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { currentStep } = this.state;

        return (
            <>
                <Step0 active={currentStep >= 0} />
                <Step1 active={currentStep >= 1} />

                <button onClick={this.handlePrev}>Prev</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleNext}>Next</button>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

the same but with a functional component

```
export const StepsSimple: React.FC = () => {
    const stepsCount = 1 // from zero;
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState(0);

    function handlePrev() {
        const result = currentStep - 1;

        setCurrentStep(result < 0 ? 0 : result);
    }

    function handleNext() {
        const result = currentStep + 1;

        setCurrentStep(result > stepsCount ? 1 : result);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Step0 active={currentStep >= 0} />
            <Step1 active={currentStep >= 1} />

            <button onClick={handlePrev}>Prev</button>
            <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

using and array of steps

```
export const  StepsUsingMap: React.FC = () => {
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState(0);

    const steps = [
        Step0,
        Step1
    ]

    const stepsCount = steps.length - 1 // from zero;

    function handlePrev() {
        const result = currentStep - 1;
        setCurrentStep(result < 0 ? 0 : result);
    }

    function handleNext() {
        const result = currentStep + 1;
        setCurrentStep(result > stepsCount ? 1 : result);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {steps.map((Step, index) => (
                <Step key={index} active={currentStep >= index} />
            ))}

            <button onClick={handlePrev}>Prev</button>
            <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

an example of steps components

```
interface Props {
    active: boolean;
}

// Step example
const Step0: React.FC<Props> = ({ active = false }) => {
    return (
        <div className={clsx({ [classes.active]: active, })}>Step0</div>
    )
}

const Step1: React.FC<Props> = ({ active = false }) => {
    return (
        <div className={clsx({ [classes.active]: active, })}>Step1</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: HI, thanks for helping me but i want to make it in class component rather than functional component

Comment: I have shown you a conception, that idea you just could use. Take a look the change I did, now it's through a class component..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-38dyq?file=/demo.tsx